# Getting empy savedState in viewmodel when using koin with compose

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, android-jetpack-compose, koin

I am using koin for dependency injection in composable. I want to use the saved state handle and get the passed arguments directly in my ViewModel. For some reason, my ViewModel is always getting null arguments. As you can see in the code below i have actually used getstateviewmodel() and i am also using the stateviewmodel way inside my module. Any help will be appreciated

My compoase Navigation:

```
@Composable
fun Navigation() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screen.Login.route) {
        composable(route = Screen.Login.route) { navBackStackEntry ->
            val viewModel : LoginViewModel =   getViewModel()
            loginScreen {
                val userId = 2

                navController.navigate(Screen.HomeScreen.route + "/$userId")
            }
        }

        composable(
            route = Screen.HomeScreen.route + "/{userId}",
            arguments = listOf(navArgument("userId") {
                type = NavType.IntType
            })
        ) {navBackStackEntry ->
            val  viewModel: HomeViewModel = getStateViewModel()
            Home(navBackStackEntry.arguments!!.getInt("userId"))
        }
    }

}
```

Koin Module:

```
val viewModelModule = module {
    viewModel { (handle: SavedStateHandle) ->HomeViewModel(handle) }
    viewModel { LoginViewModel() }

}
```

Code inside Viewmodel:

```
class HomeViewModel (savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {

    val id : MutableState<Int> = mutableStateOf(savedStateHandle["userId"]?:0)
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using it correctly? https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/viewmodel/#state-handle-injection shows a bit different example